# POST request when <input> is not inside the <form>

Tags: python, html, python-requests

Here is the HTML:

```
<form align="right" action="/search/" method="POST"></form>
<td width="88%" valign="middle" align="right">
    <input size="20" type="text" name="search" maxlength="100"
        style="width:100px;" value="Но"
        onload="if (value == '') {value ='поиск'}"
        onfocus="if (value == 'поиск') {value =''}"
        onblur="if (value == '') {value = 'поиск'}">
</td>
```

I use Requests module to make a POST request:

```
r = requests.post(
    'http://spb24.net/companies//search/',
    data = {'search' : 'Новый ресурс'}
)
```

But:

```
print(r.text)
```

returns input's default value:

```
<FORM  align="right" ACTION="/search/" METHOD=POST>
<TD width=88% valign="middle" align="right">
<INPUT size=20 TYPE="text" NAME="search" MAXLENGTH=100 style="width:100px;" VALUE="поиск"
```

Is it because the input tag is not inside the form?
Or have I just made some mistake in the code?

Comment: I have edited the indendation of your code examples, but can you please check if this is correct `http://spb24.net/companies//search/` (double slash before search) and also the output of `r.text` has an input tag which is not closed (> is missing at the end.

Comment: I added form's action to the page adress, that's why there is double slash in the url. But it is still not working if I left only one slash. And what is the 'text' parameter, how can I send it?

Comment: @CBroe where have you seen a field named "text" in the form exactly ? The one I see is name "search" and the OP _does_ pass a "search" param...

Comment: @cezar Thank you for your edits